# Get data back after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using AJAX to run a php file and send data with it.
Currently I use

```
complete: function() {
              location.reload();
          }
```

To reload the page after the php file is done. What I want is that when there is an error in the external php file, an alert is displayed (Bootstrap). Displaying an alert is not the problem, I have a function for that that accepts the string and type of alert but that is in PHP. That leads me to two questions;

How do I get data back from the AJAX call?

How do I use that data to display an alert with a PHP function (after a reload possibly)?

Thanks!

EDIT: In my external php file I have:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$error = 1;
echo json_encode($error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the complete will get the `HTML` in the `response` of the php =)

```
complete: function(response) {
    if(response==''){
        location.reload();
    }else{
        //another code here
    }
}
```

PS: Complete answer in the comments

Comment: Thanks! How should I specify the contents of the response?

Comment: you coul print  like
`<? echo "1" ?>` to set a good answer
and if there is an error
`<? echo "2" ?>` Or `<? if($error==true){echo "error";}else{echo "success";}` then with the response in javascript
`if(response =='error'){ //code to call the dialog}`

Comment: thank you but if I check if response="1" and echo "1" the page does not reload. Don't I need to do something with JSON? Edit: I get back an [object Object], so probably something with JSON I guess?

Comment: in your php whatever you prints outs its what you get in the var response of the complete function , you could send a json string too and use `var obj=$.parseJSON(response);` and use the obj like a javascript object, that answer your questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script see this post to send an JSON objets by default

Comment: I get an object Object back as response. I do not know how I should properly return from my other php file?

Comment: use a `console.log(response)` it will tell you the properties of the object, you can put the php function to know what you retrieve to the ajax?

Comment: The console gives back a responseText: "1" in the object. I updated my question with my php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64587/discussion-between-ernesto-and-bastiaan).